# Plotting Graph using Jqplot with data from Sqlite database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, jqplot

I have an activity which inserts data into the db. What I am looking for is to get the data from the database. It is a `SQLite` database. I need the data in the form of a multidimensional array using Javascript in order to plot a graph using the retrieved values in `jqPlot`.

Please, I have searched a long time with no result.

Please help, I know to plot using hard coded values but not with the values coming from database.

Please help.

Comment: Can you show the code you have already? Also, take some time asking a question. It is/was filled with errors in grammer and punctuation.

Comment: @ Guido Gautier  <!-- Sql lite code block -->  db.transaction(function(transaction) { transaction.executeSql('SELECT date, Weight  FROM Weight;', [],function(transaction, result) {if(result != null && result.rows != null) {alert(result.rows.length);// put all the rows containing date in one array // put all the rows containing weight in one array // take the 1 column of the date as well as  weight and put them as 1 array  //Above code yet to be done (no idea how to go about) //var line1= [ [x axis values] , [ y axis values] ] ;  to put in jqplot graph

Comment: var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [ /*line1 */] , {title: 'Date Vs Calories',series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}], axes: { xaxis: {label:'Date', renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,tickOptions: {angle: -40}}, yaxis:{label:'Calories / sec' ,labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer, labelOptions: {fontFamily: 'Georgia, Serif', fontSize: '12pt' } } } });

Comment: does anybody know the above query which i have not been able to find yet ... please help

Comment: This is not really my field of expertise. Please paste the relevant code **in your question**, this way people can read it easier and you can expect more answers. I will upvote your question for more visbility, once you have the code pasted in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

done at last :) , works !!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Weight  ;', [],
function(transaction, result) {
alert( result.rows.length);
var line1=[];
if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
var row = result.rows.item(i);
```

line1[i] = [row.date, row.Weight];
    } //for loop close

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
title: 'Date  Vs Calories',series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}],axes: {xaxis: {label:'Date',renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,tickOptions: {angle: -40}},yaxis:{label:'Calories / sec' ,labelRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer, labelOptions: {fontFamily: 'Georgia, Serif', fontSize: '12pt' } } }});});

} //if loop close
})// transaction.executesql
}); //function transcation 
</script>

<body> 
<div id="chart1" style="height:400px;width:300px;"></div>
</body>
```